# error using the colfilt function in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing

```
function vars = nonlinear(f)
p = colfilt(f , [3 , 3] ,'sliding',@vimabsolute);
imshow (p);
end

function v = vimabsolute(A)
[a ~] = size(A);
q =rand(1,a);
v = q * A;
end

B = colfilt(A,[M N],'sliding',FUN) rearranges each M-by-N sliding
neighborhood of A into a column in a temporary matrix, and then applies
the function FUN to this matrix. FUN must return a row vector containing
a single value for each column in the temporary matrix. (Column
compression functions such as SUM return the appropriate type of
output.) colfilt then rearranges the vector returned by FUN into a
matrix of the same size as A.
```

I just want to try if the colfilt function could work.As the documentation mentioned,A is a 9 by MN matrice,but Running it returns error message

```
Error  using * 
MTIMES does not fully support integer classes. At least one input must be scalar
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How are you loading your image?

Comment: @excaza   f = imread('XX.jpg') and nonlinear(f)

Answer (score 0):

Although the documentation for [`mtimes`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mtimes.html) seems to imply it supports integer data types, the error message you're getting shows it clearly doesn't. Your variable `q` is of type [`double`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/double.html), but your matrix `A` is an integer type, probably [`uint8`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uint8.html) as most images are. I'm not sure what result you're hoping to get from your function, but it looks like you will need to cast `A` to a `double` to perform the operation. Here are a couple options you have:

```
v = q * double(A);         % Cast A to double, result will now be double
v = uint8(q * double(A));  % Cast back to uint8, results will be uint8
                           %   and thus rounded off to nearest integer
```

Comment: Thanks! I wanna use this function to accomplish the Local Histogram Processing and try a single 'q' to see how it works.I find this function is somewhat like the CNN that same uses im2col and col2im,is it right?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with the processing you're doing. I only know that you'll probably have to do it using `double` types, then convert to whatever the desired type is for the resulting image.